# Go to Specific Record from Double click in ListBox in Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2013

I have a `Group Form` with 2 Text boxes `Group` , `GName`, where user can edit the record if required.
`Group` is Primary Key for `GroupTbl`, Data types is `Small Text`

There is another form, `Search Group` which has ListBox `listGroup`listing all groups in 2 columns `Group` , `GName`. When user Double clicks on item from the list box, I want to take them to that group in `Group Form`.

I tried the below Code.

```
Private Sub listGroup_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo listGroup_DblClick_Err
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmGroupReport", acNormal, , "[Group] = " &  Me.listGroup.Value, , acNormal

'For Error handling
listGroup_DblClick_Exit:
Exit Sub
listGroup_DblClick_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume listGroup_DblClick_Exit
End Sub
```

When user double clicks, it gives a dialogue box `Enter Parameter Value`

The list box Property `Bound Column` is set to 1

The similar code, I am using for "Client", there it is working, the only difference is that, there, the Primary key is AutoNumber.

Here are the screenshots of the same.
[image: GroupSearch Form]

When Clicked on 1st Record - G1
[image: When Clicked on 1st Record - G1]

When Clicked on 2nd Record - G2
[image: When Clicked on 2nd Record - G2]

Comment: The similar code, I am using for "Client", there it is working, the only difference is that, there, the Primary key is AutoNumber.

Answer (score 2):

If the Group field is text then you need to add single quotes to your parameter string.

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmGroupReport", acNormal, , "[Group] = '" &  Me.listGroup.Value & "'", , acNormal
```

Comment: As mentioned in the question Group is `Small Text` so this is almost certainly the correct answer.

Comment: I am now getting Msg Box as `Enter parameter value` `Forms!frmGroupReport!Group`